# TSQL count distinct

Tags: sql, t-sql, select, count, distinct

I am trying to get the unique values out from a table, the table holds the following as a time log file:

```
id | time | code | user
1  | 7000 | xxxx | 1 
2  | 7000 | xxxx | 1
3  | 7500 | xxxx | 2
4  | 7000 | xxxx | 3
```

What I would like to know is how many unique users have used the code at time, e.g. 7000, it should say 2 but with the distinct I write I get 3

```
SELECT Time, COUNT(*) as total, Code
FROM dbo.AnalyticsPause
WHERE CODE = 'xxxx'
GROUP BY  id, Time, Code
```

Result:

```
time | Count | code 
7000 | 3     | xxxx
7500 | 1     | xxxx
```

where I would like to have

```
time | Count | code 
7000 | 2     | xxxx
7500 | 1     | xxxx
```

How would I be able to add a distinct on the id_user and still count all the time together

Comment: Please specify the DBMS that you are using.

Comment: @imankurpatel000 the use of `dbo` seems to suggest [tag:sql-server]

Comment: it is TSQL as in the title :)

Comment: TSQL (or spelled correctly: **T-SQL**) can still by either Sybase or Microsoft SQL Server - please add the proper, relevant tag to your question

Comment: ok i don't know the difference in those two, i use Azure so i guess it's Microsoft SQL server

Answer (score 26, accepted):

`count(*)` counts the total number of rows (in the group). You should instead just count the `distinct user`:

```
SELECT   Time, COUNT(DISTINCT user) as total, Code
FROM     dbo.AnalyticsPause
WHERE    code = 'xxxx'
GROUP BY Time, Code
```

Comment: i think this works, need to run some test on the actual code but it seems promissing :)

Comment: Leave out `id` from the `group by` clause, then it should work. The `code` can also be removed from the `group by` clause, as it is already used in the where clause.